# Trouble with Django-Kronos

Tags: django

I have a weird problem with [Django-Kronos](https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos).

I've got it running successfully on my local machine and on our development server. However, on the production server, I can't get kronos to acknowledge my cron.py file. When I run installtasks, it runs but says "0 tasks installed". I've also tried running the tasks manually and kronos tells me the task doesn't exist.

We use git to push everything through to the server, so all the files and the structures are identical between the three locations. I've also checked and the cron.py file exists and has exactly the same content as the working servers.

The only differences between the servers is that the production server is running Postgres (SQlite on the dev server) and it's Ubuntu 12.10, whereas the dev server is 12.01.

Kronos is functioning properly, but it's not picking up our cron.py file for some reason....

Any got any ideas?!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, our solution was to scrap Django-Kronos altogether and create a custom management command which we're running from the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when one of import you are trying to make is not there, your production system might be missing some Python package which is included in your cron.py.